# Managing DBCP connections with 45 second idle drop

Tags: mysql, spring, apache-commons-dbcp

We have a Java web application that utilizes several different connections to a variety of database servers. Somewhat recently, a couple databases servers (managed by a different department) were reconfigured to sit behind a firewall which cuts any 45 second idle connection. I was told that there should be a keepAlive property for our connections that we can set. However, that doesn't seem to be the case after some research. Instead I have to come to the conclusion that I must use properties like:

- validationQuery
- testOnBorrow
- timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis
- etc. (Source: [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html))

The short of it is I have to ensure that the application retains its connection to these servers regardless of the 45 second timeout on the other side. I've run through a few configurations with little success (Example: When the connection drops, the connection is re-established sooner, but still drops rather quickly).

Here is the original code for the BasicDataSource object:

```
private BasicDataSource createDefaultDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setInitialSize(3);
    ds.setMinIdle(1);
    ds.setMaxIdle(5);
    ds.setMaxActive(100);
    ds.setMaxWait(3 * 1000);
    ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30 * 1000);
    ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(60 * 1000);
    ds.setLogAbandoned(true);
    ds.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    ds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);

    return ds;
}
```

And here is what I assumed would be the solution, yet doesn't seem to work how I expect:

```
private BasicDataSource createDefaultDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setInitialSize(3);
    ds.setMinIdle(1);
    ds.setMaxIdle(5);
    ds.setMaxActive(100);
    ds.setMaxWait(3 * 1000);
    ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(15 * 1000); // was 30 seconds
    ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30 * 1000);  // was 60 seconds
    ds.setLogAbandoned(true);
    ds.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    ds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);

    ds.setValidationQuery("select 1");
    ds.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    ds.setTestOnReturn(true);
    ds.setTestWhileIdle(true);

    return ds;
}
```

Maybe my timing is off, perhaps there are other properties I have to set in conjunction to these, or maybe I should be going about this a different way.

What properties should be set/changed in order to make up for a 45 second idle drop policy?